# GNU parallel -Dall option

Tags: parallel-processing

Like in the title, what is the "-Dall" option, what does it do exactly?

```
parallel -Dall .....
```

I see it provides more context but when I tried to find some documentation on it I was not able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-D controls debugging. -Dall = all debugging.

The reason why there is no documentation is because the output changes between versions. In other words: You should *never* rely on the the output from -Dall.

Instead of understanding that output your time is better spent on reading
https://zenodo.org/record/1146014 and
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html